# How can I send data fetched from core data to another VC?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm new to programming and I have a to do list app that uses core data. The user inputs information and from there it is stored into a coreData database. In my UITableView I create a fetch request and store the data into an array, the code looks like this.

```
    var tasks: Array<AnyObject> = []

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let contexts: NSManagedObjectContext = appDeleg.managedObjectContext!
    let fetchreq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "toDo")

    tasks = contexts.executeFetchRequest(fetchreq, error: nil)!
    tableView.reloadData()

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let CellID: NSString = "myCell"

    var cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as CustomCell

    if let indexpth = indexPath as NSIndexPath! {

        var data: NSManagedObject = tasks[indexpth.row] as NSManagedObject
        cell.theTextLabel?.text = data.valueForKeyPath("toDoName") as? String

        cell.theDetailTextLabel?.text = data.valueForKeyPath("toDoNumber") as? String

    }
```

Displaying the data in a table view works perfectly, but I want to make something slightly more complicated. When the user clicks on a cell, I want to create a push segue to another VC where the data will be displayed in labels. My question is, how can I achieve passing only the data displayed in the cell that was clicked to a view controller that will display the data in more detail.

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

```
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

        var detailVC: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController

        var index: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()! //Index path for cell
        var row: NSInteger = index.row // Converting NSIndexPath to int 

        var theData: NSManagedObject = tasks[row] as NSManagedObject
        //here I would pass info from theData to the DetailViewController

        detailVC.theObjectImPassingTo = theData
    }

}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to pass that data so it would stay in the form of a managed object and what kind of variable I would need in my DetailViewController to store the data in. I've tried a few things but my limited experience isn't enough to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`prepareForSegue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:)

> Discussion
>   The default implementation of this method does nothing. Your view controller overrides this method when it needs to pass relevant data to the new view controller. The segue object describes the transition and includes references to both view controllers involved in the segue.

That will give you a method with references to both view controllers and allow you to pass data from the source view controller to the destination view controller via whatever methods or properties you define to accept that data.

In your case perhaps you need to keep track of the selected cell on your source controller and add a property which accepts an identifier of whatever "todo" model you defined in Core Data to the destination controller.

---

When working with Core Data entities how you reference them depends on how they will be used and how you setup your managed object contexts. If your controllers share a managed object context then you can just pass model instances back and forth since you'll be working in the same context and on the same thread. If your controllers use (or might want to use) different contexts to isolate their changes then I prefer to pass model identifier and have each controller load the corresponding models independently. That can be unnecessary overhead but I find it can also make the controller easier to reuse and change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jonah!. I've edited my code to add the prepare for segue method. I should have mentioned that I knew how to pass data from one vc to another using the prepareForSegue method, but I only know how to pass normal data, I'm not familiar with passing CoreData information and in what kind of object I would drop the data in the DetailViewController. Cheers!

Comment: I added some comments about referencing Core Data entities, hope that's useful. Is there something more specific I can answer?

Comment: For now I'm fine, I'll try to use your comments in order to find a solution myself so I can learn, if I'm having too much trouble and can't solve my problem I'll come back here and ask for more help... thanks!